# Kotlin - Static get/set Functions in Java Class Are Not Recognised as Properties

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider the following code:

java/com.example

```java
public class Foo {
    public static int getStaticProperty() { return 0; }
    public static void setStaticProperty(int value) { }

    public int getInstanceProperty() { return 0; }
    public void setInstanceProperty(int value) { }
}
```

Accessing the Java class from Kotlin shows instance get/set methods as properties, but the same is not so for the static get/set methods; for example:

kotlin/com.example

```kotlin
Foo.getStaticProperty()
Foo.setStaticProperty(123)
Foo.staticProperty = 123 // Doesn't work

val x = Foo()
x.instanceProperty = 123 // Does work
```

Why doesn't Kotlin recognise static get/set methods as properties?

Comment: @SergeyVasnev your comment does not make any sense. As for this question itself, I don't know why it doesn't work for you, it works perfectly fine for me. What version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: @Alex.T Kotlin 1.2

Comment: that is slightly older than what I checked it on. I can at least confirm to you that it works fine on version `1.4.10`. I don't know if that functionality was added in `1.3` or `1.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: this feature is not yet supported in Kotlin.

Converting Java accessor-like methods to synthetic Kotlin properties is currently supported only for instance methods. But for static methods this feature is not yet supported. You can track its state in this issue: [KT-44183](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44183).